# GORM-Table for hierarchy-how to change the table name in domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am working on Grails GORM.
I have a base domain class as below:

```
abstract class BaseDomain {
String createdBy
String updatedBy

static constraints = {
}
}
```

and extended class as below:

```
class Customer extends BaseDomain {

String name
String address1
String address2
String city
String state
String zip
String phone    

static constraints = {

}

}
```

When I execute run-app, a table is created with name: BASE_DOMAIN

I added the following to change the table name:

```
static mapping = {
  table 'customer_table' 
}
```

It's throwing the following exception:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Invocation of init method
 failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:
 Duplicate class/entity mapping com.samples.Customer
        ... 3 more
     Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.samples.Customer
```

Can anyone let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The `BASE_DOMAIN` table is being created because of the BaseDomain abstract class, and not the Customer class.

You probably want to move the abstract class to `src/groovy`, then it won't try to create a table for it.

This is related to [a change introduced in Grails 2.0](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.x/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html) I think, in previous Grails versions abstract classes didn't persist abstract classes.

Comment: I moved the abstract class to src/groovy as you said. but still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Is it still `duplicate class/entity mapping`? Maybe you need to do a `grails clean`, after moving the file.